# Proving density of $\mathbb Q^p$ in $\mathbb{R}^p$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

I'm bringing here an interesting analysis exercise:

> Prove that $\mathbb{Q}^p=\lbrace (q_1,q_2,...,q_p): q_i \in \mathbb{Q}, 1\leq i\leq p \rbrace$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^p$,
>   i.e. prove that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^p$ and for all $r>0$ exists $q=q(x)\in \mathbb{Q}^p $ such that $||x-q||_2<r$, or equivalently prove that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^p$ and for all $r>0$ , $B_r(x)\cap \mathbb{Q}^p \neq \emptyset$.

I think i have proved it, but I'm not sure if my proof is correct, it would be helpful if you see any mistake or tell me if it's correct. Here's my proof:

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $0<r\in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary vector and number, respectively. Then to prove the exercise, some $q\in \mathbb{Q}^p$ must satisfy $||x-q||_2<r$. So I choose $z \in \mathbb{R}^p$, such that $z\in B_r(x)$. Let $C=\lbrace tx+(1-t)z,\  0<t<1 \rbrace$. It's evident that any $v\in C$ satisfies $||x-v||_2<r$. I choose $y\in C,\ y=(y_1,y_2,...,y_p)$ So it must happen that

$\min\lbrace x_i,z_i \rbrace<y_i<\max \lbrace x_i,z_i\rbrace \quad \forall i=1,...,p$. In any case, $\min\lbrace x_i,z_i \rbrace \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\max \lbrace x_i,z_i\rbrace \in\mathbb{R}$. So, i use the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. So for any $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$ exists $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a<q<b$. Then use this fact and let $y_i=q_i$ for all $i=1,...,p$. Then $q\in  \mathbb{Q}^p$ and $q\in B_r(x)$. Consequently $\mathbb{Q}^p$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^p.$

That's my argument, i would appreciate any advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The box and euclidian topology are equivalent. Thus it suffices to show that $\mathbb Q $ is dense in $\mathbb R $.

Comment: In my class, we already prove That Q is dense in R, but, Since my course is not just on topology, I didn't see equivalences in topology. But thanks anyway!

Comment: I actually don't think your argument is quite correct:  $C$ may not pass through any rational points at all.  For example, if $x = (\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ and $z = (\sqrt{2},0) $, the points on $C$ have the form $(\sqrt{2}, t\sqrt{2})$ which is never in $\mathbb{Q}^2$.

Comment: Oh, I see.. And adding that convexity would not stand over other metric spaces, my proof is a total failure.

Comment: @JasonDeVito My instructor told me to prove it analizing component by component. For all $j=1,...,p$ exists $q_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $|x_j -q_j|<\frac{r}{\sqrt{p}}$ implying that $||x-q||_2 ^2 = (x_1-q_1)^2 + ...+ (x_p-q_p)^2 < \frac{r^2}{p} + ...+  \frac{r^2}{p} =r^2$ I think it works

Comment: I wouldn't call it a total failure ;-)  I agree that youcan prove it component wise just as your instructor instructed.

Comment: Thank you, Jason. Will do! :)

Answer (score 3):

Your argument is a bit confused, but at a glance it seems correct.

It's simpler if you use the $\infty$-norm:
$$
\|(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\|_\infty=\max\{|x_1|,|x_2|,\dots,|x_n|\}
$$
Given $x$ and $r$, just choose $q_i\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $|x_i-q_i|<r$, which is possible because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Then, by the very definition, $\|(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)-(q_1,q_2,\dots,q_n)\|_\infty<r$.

Now, if you want to use the $2$-norm, just recall that $\|x\|_\infty\le\sqrt{n}\|x\|_2$

Comment: Right know I see That my set C is confuse. And for general metric spaces, the notion of convex may have no sense. Thanks